# How do you adjust the drop down cell position to pop up instead of down using handsontable?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, handsontable

I want to flip the position of the handsontable dropdown cell menu so it pops up instead of down. The cell uses jQuery Autocomplete and I think this setting will do what I want:

```
position {
    my: "left bottom",
    at: "left top",
    collision: "flip flip"
};
```

But I can't seem to pass it into handsontable.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ea47q2m6/2/)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Never figured this one out... I will have to take a look again.